1 hour timeout using Airflow calling Oracle stored procedures running in AKS
I have to move an airflow instance from a standalone server to Azure Kubernetes. The existing DAG we used makes many calls to Oracle stored procedures and they can sometimes take hours to finish. So timeout issue is not with the database.
Using the same DAG on AKS it times out at exactly 1 hour to the second. We are using istio in our AKS setup, so I have tried some Destination rules and listener-timeout-tcp EnvoyRules. I have also put expire-timeout-30 on the extra parameters on my Oracle connection in Airflow.
Here is the error:
[2024-09-30, 01:00:02 UTC] {base.py:84} INFO - Using connection ID 'NBI_TRANSFORM' for task execution.
[2024-09-30, 01:00:02 UTC] {base.py:84} INFO - Using connection ID 'NBI_TRANSFORM' for task execution.
[2024-09-30, 01:00:02 UTC] {warnings.py:112} WARNING - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/***/providers/common/sql/hooks/sql.py:560: AirflowProviderDeprecationWarning: Using conn.schema to pass the Oracle Service Name is deprecated.
                        Please use conn.extra.service_name instead.
  with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
[2024-09-30, 01:00:02 UTC] {sql.py:495} INFO - Running statement: DECLARE
                <CALL TO STORED PROCEDURE HERE>
               END;, parameters: None
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:441} ▼ Post task execution logs
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2905} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 465, in _execute_task
    result = _execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 432, in _execute_callable
    return execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 401, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 288, in execute
    output = hook.run(
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/hooks/sql.py", line 442, in run
    self._run_command(cur, sql_statement, parameters)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/hooks/sql.py", line 500, in _run_command
    cur.execute(sql_statement)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/cursor.py", line 710, in execute
    impl.execute(self)
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/cursor.pyx", line 196, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinCursorImpl.execute
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 440, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_single_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 441, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_single_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 409, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 387, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 454, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._receive_packet
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/packet.pyx", line 715, in oracledb.thin_impl.ReadBuffer.wait_for_packets_sync
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/transport.pyx", line 334, in oracledb.thin_impl.Transport.read_packet
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/errors.py", line 195, in _raise_err
    raise error.exc_type(error) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
Help: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#dpy-4011
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1206} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=bmg_test_orc_operator, task_id=task_sql, run_id=scheduled__2024-09-29T01:00:00+00:00, execution_date=20240929T010000, start_date=20240930T010001, end_date=20240930T020002
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:110} ERROR - Failed to execute job 2230 for task task_sql (DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
Help: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#dpy-4011; 228)
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:243} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:3503} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2024-09-30, 02:00:02 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:222} ▲▲▲ Log group end

Tried adding Destination rules to Istio and EnvoyFilters

Seems to be related to Istio’s default timeout settings. What is your current timeout value? 1hr is default, I guess.  You can once disable this timeout by configuring the destination rule for your Oracle service and check
